# Adding a custom command with the file name as a target

Tags: cmake

I'd like to do something like `add_custom_command`, with the output file
name as a target in the generated makefile. Is there an elegant way of
doing this?

All the examples I've seen (such as [the CMake FAQ re: latex](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_CMake_to_build_LaTeX_documents.3F)) use `add_custom_command` to tell how to generate the desired output file, and then `add_custom_target` to create a target. For example.:

```
add_executable (hello hello.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT hello.bin
                   COMMAND objcopy --output-format=binary hello hello.bin
                   DEPENDS hello
                   COMMENT "objcopying hello to hello.bin")
add_custom_target(bin ALL DEPENDS hello.bin)
```

However, the target name in the generated makefile is then `bin` rather
than `hello.bin`. Is there a way to make `hello.bin` itself a target
in the generated makefile?

Some solutions I've tried that don't work:

- Changing to: `add_custom_target(hello.bin ALL DEPENDS hello.bin)` results in a circular dependency in the makefile.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it by generating your hello.bin as a side effect of a target. Instead of generating hello.bin from objcopy, you generate hello.tmp. Then as a side effect you also copy hello.tmp to hello.bin. Finally, you create the phony target hello.bin that depends on your hello.tmp. In code:

```
add_executable (hello hello.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT hello.tmp
                   COMMAND objcopy --output-format=binary hello hello.tmp
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy hello.tmp hello.bin
                   DEPENDS hello
                   COMMENT "objcopying hello to hello.bin")
add_custom_target(hello.bin ALL DEPENDS hello.tmp)
```

The problem with that is that hello.bin is not cleaned when you run clean. To get that working, add:

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES hello.bin)
```