# CMake: Add executable for add_custom_target

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code

I have a CMakeLists.txt and some toolchain files. In my CMakeLists.txt I have a statement to generate a .elf executable. This executable is then run through some commands (using add_custom_target, code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278444/adding-a-custom-command-with-the-file-name-as-a-target)) that generates a .gba file, which is the REAL executable I want to launch. Now the problem is that I'm using the cmake extension for VS Code and the target does not show up to launch (probably because it's not considered an executable).
I tried add_executable(target.gba IMPORT), but that didn't work.
In CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(target.elf ${SOURCE_FILES} ${INCLUDE_FILES} ${EXTRA_DATA_FILES}) # Create the elf file
add_gba_executable(target.elf) # Generate the .gba from the .elf
```

In the toolchain file:

```
function(add_gba_executable target)
    get_filename_component(target_name ${target} NAME_WE)
    add_custom_target(${target_name}.gba ALL SOURCES
        COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} -v -O binary ${target} ${target_name}.gba
        COMMAND ${GBAFIX} ${target_name}.gba
        DEPENDS ${target}
        VERBATIM
    )
    set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=${target_name}.map -specs=gba.specs")
    set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES ${target_name}.gba)
endfunction()
```

How can I tell CMake the result of the add_custom_target is an executable too? I tried add_executable(target.gba IMPORT), but that didn't work.

**EDIT:** Clarification - My function already adds a target target.gba and it can be selected to be BUILT (so add_custom_target does indeed work), but does NOT show up in the list of targets to be LAUNCHED.

Comment: If your goal is to have a target seen by vscode, can't you just create a custom target that runs the generated executable? (note that you probably have to make the custom target which runs it depend on the one that generates it so that it gets built before being run)

Comment: add_custom_target is enough to enable BUILDING the target (so it is "seen" by VS Code), but it does not show up to be LAUNCHED. So it is probably not recognized as an executable.